# Не получается обработать маршрут api в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть маршрут `Route::get('{id}', 'Api/V1/ProfileController@getUser');`

И метод для него

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function getUser($id) {
        return response()->json(User::find($id),200);
    }

}
```

Пытаюсь его вызвать `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/2` и получаю 404 ошибку, срабатывает только в том случае, если использовать замыкание

```
Route::get('{id}', function ($id) {
    return response()->json(User::find($id),200);
});
```

Comment: Сугубо личное мнение, но Рут должен писаться  Route::get('/{id}', 'Api/V1/ProfileController@getUser');  , т.е. у Вас должен быть слэш перед параметром

Comment: шо /{id} шо {id} одно и тоже, да и проблема то в другом

Comment: покажите группу

Comment: да уж разобрался

Comment: Я бы ещё и версию указывал. Так как в 8-ке по другому.

Answer (score 1):

Написал так:

```
Api/V1/ProfileController@getUser`
```

, а надо было так:

```
Api\V1\ProfileController@getUser
```

Comment: Надо уже использовать `use Api\V1\ProfileController;` и
`Route::get('/route', [ProfileController::class, 'getUser']);`

Comment: А ещё на одном из проектов под старые лары видел такую реализацию
`use Api\V1\ProfileController` и непосредственно в самом вызове роута `Route::get('/route', ProfileController::class.'@functionName')` что бы проще изменять неймспейсы для большого количества роутов